# _sopen_s and fopen .. what to be used?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to read a file from a driver for 3rd party application 
(simple C absed DLL runnning in user space but under control of the 3rd party application)

This file will be written to by an separate C# application.

What shall I use so that I do not face any problems?

What is advantage of using _sopen_s over fopen, I understand the former is more secure but what is the feature of 'sharing' it supports?

I did Google it out number of tims but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_sopen_s is a secure version of open() with sharing. It uses unbuffered I/O. It works with file handles (int). This is Microsoft specific. open() is cross platform. There's also sopen() which is the shared/access version.

fopen uses buffering and no file sharing. Works with FILE* structures.
File sharing means that you allow other processes to access the file (or not). E.g. when read sharing is denied, another process will not be open the file for reading.

All are legitimate to use. The unbuffered I/O versions work faster if you read the file in large chunks.

Comment: which function can be used with FILE* structures to get file modification timestamp?

Comment: also, can we use both buffered I/O and unbuffered I/O functions inside same DLL?

Comment: Use the 'fstat' family of functions to get the modification time and other metadata. You can safely use both buffered and unbuffered. These mechanisms are orthogonal. Just don't use them on the same file :)

Comment: MSDN sample used _sopen_s() with _fstat(). If we try to use _fstat() with FILE* functions, I am getting crash

Comment: Use _fileno to convert FILE* to the low lvel file descriptor: _fstat(_fileno(pFile), &buff)